# How can you have a Flink-process evaluate multiple independent conditions for the same time window

Tags: apache-flink

So, we have events a, b, c, x,y, z in kafka source within 10 minute window and I have flink code with 10 minute window (keyed, tumplingwindow).

I have conditions to fire for (in the 10 miniute window)

1. a && b && c
2. a && z
3. b && x && y
4. a && e
5. a && f

It is clear that only the first three conditions will evaluate to true in the 10 min window.

I want each of the three to issue a trigger to a kafka sink for those events (so three(3) triggers for this example-sent to kafka sink).

I checked the examples and I have a full test harness with kafka producer, consumer and Flink processor. But it is not clear from any of the examples how to evaluate multiple independent conditions on data within the same time window.

This is just a conceptual example. In reality, there will be 200,000 - 400,000 conditions to evaluate against the incoming stream (millions of events). Someone mentioned that normally, you'd use something like drools (or a rules engine), but in this specific case the RETE won't scale at all, and recommended I check out one of the complex-event-stream processors--that are more geared to large data.

Sorry, this is already long question, but I wanted to give a good context so flink-experts would better judge. Thanks.

Comment: Just a clarification, so the data that is coming in kafka source are from different accounts, and each account would probably have 10-20 conditions. Only the conditions belonging to the accounts for the events in the timewindow will actually be evaluated at a given instant---not all 400,000 conditions. Overall, when you factor in the number of accounts and conditions per account, you get a 300,000-400,000 conditions. The example assumes all the events are from the same account, and all the conditions are from that account.

Comment: Actually Flink now doesn't support multiple rules for cep processing, which may not be the best option for you. I would choose a stateful operator to help achieve this. Firstly, load all rules into memory, then update the matching status when receiving every element, and output a trigger flag if condition is satisfied, at last use trigger to evaluate based on the trigger flag.

Comment: Hi bupt_ljy, thanks. I found this article which you might find useful: https://www.ververica.com/blog/bettercloud-dynamic-alerting-apache-flink. It seems very possible. I was thinking of it the wrong way. Their approach leverages the streaming design of flink and a pipeline sequence of steps--you set the rules into a "control" stream and then join the two based on which rules qualify for an event. Then you have a pre-filtering and then a count processor. The count processor determines whether you have an alert for the set of events/rules.